# PHP/Laravel trim all but last word in a namespace

Tags: php, string, laravel, laravel-5, trim

Trying to trim a fully qualified namespace so to use just the last word. Example namepspace is `App\Models\FruitTypes\Apple` where that final word could be any number of fruit types. Shouldn't this...

```
$fruitName = 'App\Models\FruitTypes\Apple';
trim($fruitName, "App\\Models\\FruitTypes\\");
```

...do the trick? It is returning an empty string. If I try to trim just `App\\Models\\` it returns `FruitTypes\Apples` as expected. I know the backslash is an escape character, but doubling should treat those as actual backslashes.

Comment: You can try to use PHP `explode` function which returns array of each word separately. So use `explode('\', $fruitName)` and use the last element of the array as the result.

Comment: Yeah, that's wacky, but I guess it works hah. Thanks! I also need to lowercase it, so end result is `strtolower(explode("\\", $fruit->fruitType)[3])`. Wacky indeed 

Comment: The second argument to `trim` is a character mask, not a specific string to trim off. It will remove any of those characters from both ends until it gets to one that's not specified in the mask.

Comment: Right you are! `strtolower(str_replace('App\\Models\\FruitTypes\\', '', $fruit->fruitType))` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use native functionality for this rather than string manipulation, then [`ReflectionClass::getShortName`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getshortname.php) will do the job:

```
$reflection = new ReflectionClass('App\\Models\\FruitTypes\\Apple');
echo $reflection->getShortName();
```

> Apple

See https://3v4l.org/eVl9v

Answer (score 0):

`preg_match()` with the regex pattern `\\([[:alpha:]]*)$` should do the trick.

```
$trimmed = preg_match('/\\([[:alpha:]]*)$/', $fruitName);
```

Your result will then live in `$trimmed[1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)'. If you don't mind the pattern being a bit less explicit, you could do:

```
preg_match('/([[:alpha:]]*)$/', $fruitName, $trimmed);
```

And your result would then be in `$trimmed[0]`.

> If `matches` is provided, then it is filled with the results of search. `$matches[0]` will contain the text that matched the full pattern, `$matches[1]` will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on.
>   <sub>[preg_match - php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)</sub>

<sup>(`matches` is the third parameter that I named `$trimmed`, see documentation for full explanation)</sup>

---

An explanation for the regex pattern

`\\` matches the character `\` literally to establish the start of the match.

The parentheses `()` create a capturing group to return the match or a substring of the match.

In the capturing group `([[:alpha:]]*)`:

`[:alpha:]` matches a alphabetic character [a-zA-Z]

The `*` quantifier means match between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible

Then `$` asserts position at the end of the string.

So basically, "Find the last `\` then return all letter between this and the end of the string".